# Why is code giving error if I try to access the array returned by str.split(), immediately in next line

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, swap

Why does it happen that the below code throws the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'arr' before initialization`

```
function swap(str,a,b){
    let arr = str.split("")
    [arr[a],arr[b]] = [arr[b],arr[a]]
    return arr.join("")
}
```

```
swap("abcde",2,4) // throws error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'arr' before initialization"
```

But as soon as I insert any dummy statement between line 2 and 3, surprisingly code starts to work

```
function swap(str,a,b){
    let arr = str.split("")
    23456; // this could be anything like a variable declaration, or any valid javascript statement
    [arr[a],arr[b]] = [arr[b],arr[a]]
    return arr.join("")
}
```

```
swap("abcde",2,4) // returns "abedc" as expected
```

I am surprised to see why does this even work now ? It should have given error in both the cases, or should have worked in both cases.
I'm sure that in the 1st case, `split` is not finishing it's work till the time line 3 is executed and in 2nd case, it is getting enough time because of 1 extra statement in between.
But I would still love to get a clear explanation as to why it is behaving like this.
I'm not sure if this is same for all browsers, but I've tried it on Chrome and Safari on mac, and both of them gave same error.

Comment: How do you call it? Share the args.

Comment: Just now I've edited it

Answer (score 3):

The semicolon is making the difference. JavaScript thinks you want to access the result of `str.split("")[arr[a],arr[b]]` like an array. This is why JavaScript autoformatters will insert a semicolon at the beginning of the next line like this:

```
function swap(str,a,b){
    let arr = str.split("")
    ;[arr[a],arr[b]] = [arr[b],arr[a]]  // <--- semicolon in front of this line
    return arr.join("")
}
```

Comment: I've tried it in browser console
No autoformatter is used here
But your explaination however seems to be correct

Comment: If you would use a formatter, than it would insert this semicolon for you. This is actually how this is supposed to be written (even though it looks wrong on first sight)

Comment: That's why I prefer using semicolons.

Comment: Using semicolon in front of statement is still something familiar
What is not familiar is, the interpreter not considering  `arr = str.split("")` as a complete statement and looking for tokens in next line. We all know that Javascript can work well even without semicolons, so this is a bit surprising to me

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax is off a bit
split will return an array and trailing it with brackets is translated as if you are trying to access an element of the array I believe you are missing the semi colon only

```
let arr = str.split("")[arr[a],arr[b]] = [arr[b],arr[a]]
```

```js
function swap(str,a,b){
    let arr = str.split("");
    [arr[a],arr[b]] = [arr[b],arr[a]]
    return arr.join("")
}

console.log(swap('some tpyo', 6, 7))
```